# angularJS modal open not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one html file.
At that file, I have a button that should open a modal when I click it.

```
   <button ng-click="open(value.Reservation.id)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ></button>
```

and below that button, in the same html file, I have the script.

```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">test</script>
```

and in the pendingController.js file,

```
   myApp.controller('PendingCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $http, $modal, $log) {

$scope.open = function (id) {

    //GET RESERVATION
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'admin/getUpdateReservation/'+ id +'.json'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.post = data.data;
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'UpdateReservationCtrl',
            resolve: {
                data: function () {
                    $scope.post.status = $scope.status;
                    $scope.post.locations = $scope.locations;
                    return $scope.post;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('error');
    });
};
```

})

And I have updateReservationController.js file.

```
  hansApp.controller('UpdateReservationCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $route, $http, $modalInstance, data) {
console.log('6');
  })
```

the console.log('6'); works. But I can't see the modal page...
How can I make my modal works?

Answer (score 0):

So First of all, dont use resolve if you dont wating for a promise...

What docs say to the resolve Key:

> Object containing dependencies that will be injected into the
>   controller's constructor when all the dependencies have resolved. The
>   controller won't load if the promise is rejected.

It looks like you are using the Modal of AngularStarp (correct me if im wrong).

As they mention in they docs you have to do something like this:

```
   modal = $modal({
            controller: function($scope) {},
            show: false,
        });
```

and in your success-callback:

```
modal.$promise.then(modal.show);
```